# UScrollView lazy loading unload view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I have a question regarding the page control sample code from apple.

in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method there's a comment:

*// A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible*

I wonder how to unload the views+controllers. As I have problems with my memory management I really need that.

Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

From your `scrollViewDidScroll` you could figure out the current coordinates the user is in from the `contentSize` with this as the user scrolls out a certain `viewController` pop that `viewController` or `view` from of the current view.

`[currentView removeFromSubView];`

You could do this but I would suggest you try to use `UITableView` as this is all damn easy to do it there...